# How do I find the tangent line for these two points?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, tangent-line

I need to find the slope of the tangent line to the circle, but I forgot how to find the tangent line for each of the points (0.8, -0.6) and (0.8, 0.6)

[image]

Comment: Take the equation of the circle, derive both sides, solve for $y'$. Remember the chain rule.

Comment: Why are there *two* circles??

Comment: The tangent cone of $(x^2+y^2-1)((x-\frac12)(x-2)+y^2)=0$ around $(\frac45,\pm\frac35)$ is $\frac3{25}(3(y\pm \frac35)\mp 4(x-\frac45))(4(y\pm \frac35)\pm 3(x-\frac45))=0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily solved using implicit differentiation.

The equation of the unit circle is $x^2+y^2=1$; take the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$, we get $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(x^2+y^2)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}1$, which gives $2x+2y\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=0$ from chain rule. Rearranging gives $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=-\frac x y$. Substitute in those coordinates, we get $m_1=-\frac{4}{3}, m_2=\frac{4}{3}$.

However, since you posted this question in the geometry tag, I will provide an alternative approach, using only coordinate geometry.

The equation of the line passing through the origin $O(0,0)$ and a point on the circle $A(x,y)$ has a slope $\frac{y}{x}$. From the property of circles, we know that the tangent is perpendicular to the radius, which means the product of their slopes is $-1$. Suppose the slope of the tangent is $m$, we get $m\frac{y}{x}=-1\implies m=-\frac x y$. The result is the same as in the calculus method.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the slope directly with the derivative like Joshua suggests.

Another way is to note that the tangent is perpendicular to the radius:

- Find the center of the circle.
- Calculate the slope of the radius to each point.
- From these, calculate the slope of the perpendicular.

Can you follow this and take it home from here?